# How to update cache to concurrent requests in Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-core

I'm using memory cache in Asp.net core and use a custom business. I need the list of roles and related data of role in memory.

I'm using the following method for the cache roles in memory:

```
public void Add(Role role)
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        var dictionary = _cache.Get<Dictionary<string, List<RoleViewModel>>>(CacheKeys.RoleCache);

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(role.Id))
        {
            dictionary[role.tId].Add(new RoleCacheViewModel(role));
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(
                role.Id,
                new List<RoleCacheViewModel> { new RoleCacheViewModel(role) });
        }

        _cache.Set(CacheKeys.RoleCache, dictionary);
    }
}
```

So, I have a lot of requests and I need it to cache in memory. for the concurrent request, I'm using lock object like the below.

Is it the correct way or I can use a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The `MemoryCache` class is thread-safe (see - https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs#L23) so you don't need to lock before inserting into the cache.

inserting into the cache is as simple as this:

```
_cache.GetOrCreate<Role>(role.Id, entry => entry.Value = role);
```

and then getting a value from the cache would be:

```
if(_cache.TryGetValue<Role>(id, out var role))
{
    // your code here...
}
```

Comment: The problem in OP is he is storing Dictionary into Cache instead of single value of role.